# Melville : Invoice to Cash Collection , Understanding the features

Tags: classification, forecasting, predictive-models

I'm trying to implement this paper by Prem Melville , Page 3 gives a list  of the features. They've used features which correspond to absolute numbers , such as

> Number of paid invoices prior to the creation
>   date of a new invoice of a customer

And many such features, which will always **increase with time**.
So for example if today you have 1000 paid invoices , an year from now , it will definitely be more than that.This feature can only *change* *in one direction*.

I don't really understand why should we even use such a feature (Trying just the above feature increases the cross validation score by roughly 1%) which doesn't reflect anything corresponding to the payment behaviour of a customer , but is just an absolute number.

Comment: Are you suggesting that knowing how many invoices a customer has paid in the past should give you *no* information about how likely they might be to pay a new invoice??

Comment: It might about how likely they are to pay an invoice  , but will it tell anything about whether they will pay on time or not? Secondly , if you take decision trees , over time there will be many nodes which will be impossible to reach just because of the nature of the feature.

Comment: The nature of your comment suggests you are asking a question about customer behavior--but not about statistics.  Whether this variable (or any other variable) is useful for predicting on-time payments is a matter for empirical investigation. But if you never use this variable in your model, you will never know, will you?

Comment: Yes and that's why I did try it out. But what about my 2nd question (in the comment ) ?

Comment: I couldn't understand that comment.  I believe it's impossible to construct a decision tree that would create unreachable nodes, since every one of them must be reached in the training dataset.

Comment: I was talking about prediction time , over time as number of invoices will only increase , there might be  nodes in the tree which were reachable for the training set , but will be impossible to reach now because the value of  this feature has permanently  'moved past' . The only solution I can think of is to keep on updating your tree model.